# How to show the number of rows of the result in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In my SQL Server Management Studio the number of rows of the result in the bottom bar has disappeared. [In the image attached is the red circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvTCo.jpg)

I have been looking for the configuration of the bar but I haven't found it. How can I show it again?
Thanks

Comment: Is that image meant to be showing that it *isn't there*?

Comment: @Larnu no, the image is to show what I mean

Comment: Tools > Options > Text Editor < Editor Tab and Status Bar > Include row count: True

Comment: @GarethD Thank you for your help! I hadn't found that option.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by modifying Options

[image: Options]